Android Studio Emulator Running but Not Visible (Out of View)
I'm encountering an issue where the Android Studio Emulator is running but not appearing on the screen. It was working fine previously, but now it's consistently out of view even when I try different device types.
Here's what I've already tried:

Restarting Android Studio
Creating new AVDs
Checking for updates to Android Studio and the emulator
Adjusting screen resolution and scaling settings

I've tried everything I can think of, but the emulator still won't show up.

Right side toolbar --> Click "Running Devices" menu. It will bring your running device/emulator

Here’s how I fixed it:

Open the emulator and run any device you want.
If the emulator is running but not visible on the screen, it’s
likely that the emulator is running out of the screen's view.
Open Task Manager: Press Ctrl + Shift + Esc or right-click on the taskbar and select Task Manager.
Go to the Processes tab and find the emulator process: Look for a process like "qemu-system-x86_64" (this may vary based on your setup).
Expand the process: Click the arrow on the right side of the emulator’s name, or right-click on it and select Expand.
Locate the emulator instance: You should see something like "Android Emulator - ..." under the expanded process.
Maximize the emulator window: Right-click on the emulator instance and choose Maximize.

That's how I solved the issue, and hopefully, it does the trick for you too!

Thanks, helped me, was banging my head where did it go in my MAUI app.

@user3656651 Happy to help! I'm glad it worked for you.

Is there any permanent solution every time we run the virtual device it must be repetitive task

Good hint, but did not work for me on Windows 11 (home edition) with AS from June. Strange is: yesterday the emulator worked just fine.

I just had a similar case where the emulator was clearly running but wasn't showing on my screen.
Here's how I fixed it:

Close the emulator. Right-click the window on the taskbar->Close Window/Task Kill or click the stop icon in Android Studio's Device Manager.

In the Device Manager on Android Studio, click the menu and choose Show On Disk.


Find and edit the emulator-user.ini file. The path will be something like: "C:\Users\YourName\.android\avd\Samsung_S24_Ultra_API_34.avd\emulator-user.ini"

Make sure the window.x and window.y coordinates are not negative values. Make them both 0 to be sure.



I hope this also solves your problem :)

Good hint, did not work for me. The device "ignored" the settings there, and overwrote it on termination (despite it is write protected!!!) with the wrong settings again. No idea from where it gets those ideas. BTW: my emulator is "only" a few hundred pixels off to the upper left.

For Visual Studio :

Make sure emulator is closed
Tools > Android > Android Device Manager
Right click on your emulator > Reveal in explorer
Open "emulator-user.ini"
make sure window.x and window.y is 0
Save and start emulator

How fix should look like


Have you  tried:
Menu -> Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB Integration.
(view  This link)
